# How to get the path of .key file from spring application programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to get the path of a key file that i have placed in the root folder of my spring application. Everything works as expected when i run it locally. But when i deploy the application to the server i get a FileNotFoundException.

```
File file = new File("testfile.key");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

I have tried placing the file in the resource folder as well.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("testfile.key").getFile());
```

Just need to pass the file path to another method (3rd party library) which will read the content.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a resource, placed in the resource folder (if using maven).

You can access it using

```
this.getClass().getResource("testfile.key");
```

The root for accessing files can change between environments but the root for resources is a directory that's specified during compilation. For maven driven projects this is:

```
src/main/resources
```

Comment: You'd need to check the documentation. I never worked with gradle but the essence of my answer stays the same: If it's there at compile time it's almost certainly a resource and not a file.